# how can I make pip/setuptools understand that my package is in ./src?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a library with a layout like this in Github:

```
README
setup.py
src/
   somelibrary.py
```

Note: I cannot change the layout, but I can change setup.py.

I want to be able to reference this library from requirements.txt, so that people can do `pip install -r requirements.txt` and have it installed automagically. So I add a line like this into requirements:

```
-e git+http://blablabla/blabla#egg=somelibrary
```

This will clone the repository under ./src/somelibrary and then run `setup.py develop` on it, which will just add a link to ./src/somelibrary under site-packages. Unfortunately, because the library is actually under ./src/somelibrary/**src**, it seems like python can't see the library correctly.

What am I missing? I guess it must be a setup.py option I'm not using correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put this in the setup function:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'},
```

That maps the base package directory to "src".

Comment: That's it. I removed the "packages" option and set package_dir as you suggested, and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: It really bugs me that this receives only the barest mention (and no explanation) in the setuptools docs: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools

Comment: A lot of things bug me about setuptools. But it's better than nothing. ;-)