# Multiple python packages in a single repository

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, pypi

Hi I'm the creator of an open source program called [GridCal](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal). This consists of a Qt-based GUI and the calculation engine. Since the beginning I've had the GUI and the engine under the same package for practical reasons. The structure below worked nicely and the packages for pypi were created correctly. This is because the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/src/setup.py) file is at the same level as the package `GirdCal`

```
repository_folder
|
|_ src
    |_ GridCal
    |     |_ GUI
    |     |_ Core
    |     |_ IO
    |     |_ Simulations
    |     |_ __init__.py
    |     
    |_ setup.py 
    |_ upload_to_pypi.py
```

Recently, I've [split the code](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/tree/the_great_split) in 2 packages (GridCal and GridCalEngine) to see if I can get a structure that works for development and for deployment to pypi.

the structure is the following:

```
repository_folder
|
|_ src
    |_ GridCal
    |     |_ GUI
    |     |_ __init__.py
    |     |_ setup.py 
    |
    |_ GridCalEngine
    |     |_ Core
    |     |_ IO
    |     |_ Simulations
    |     |_ __init__.py
    |     |_ setup.py 
    |
    |_ upload_to_pypi.py
```

This split structure works very well for development since the GUI can properly reference the engine, the generated packages are checked and uploaded to pypi, but when installing those packages, the installation fails because the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/the_great_split/src/GridCalEngine/setup.py) file is not outside the package like in the previous example.

I have seen resources like [this](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/tree/master) and other [relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265944/python-multiple-packages-in-one-repository-or-one-package-per-repository) in SO, but they do not address the issue of generating packages that are installable.

**How can I solve the `setup.py` file location issue?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own code for packaging:

```
# This file is part of GridCal
#
# GridCal is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GridCal is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GridCal.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import os
import sys
import tarfile
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Tuple
from subprocess import call


def build_setup_cfg() -> str:
    """
    Generate the content of setup.cgf
    :return:
    """
    val = '[egg_info]\n'
    val += 'tag_build = \n'
    val += 'tag_date = 0\n'

    return val


def build_pkg_info(name: str,
                   version: str,
                   summary: str,
                   home_page: str,
                   author: str,
                   email: str,
                   license_: str,
                   keywords: str,
                   classifiers_list: List[str],
                   requires_pyhon: str,
                   description_content_type: str,
                   provides_extra: str,
                   long_description: str):
    """
    Generate the content of PKG-INFO
    :param name:
    :param version:
    :param summary:
    :param home_page:
    :param author:
    :param email:
    :param license_:
    :param keywords:
    :param classifiers_list:
    :param requires_pyhon:
    :param description_content_type:
    :param provides_extra:
    :param long_description:
    :return:
    """
    val = 'Metadata-Version: 2.1\n'
    val += "Name: " + name + '\n'
    val += "Version: " + version + '\n'
    val += "Summary: " + summary + '\n'
    val += "Home-page: " + home_page + '\n'
    val += "Author: " + author + '\n'
    val += "Author-email: " + email + '\n'
    val += "License: " + license_ + '\n'
    val += "Keywords: " + keywords + '\n'

    for classifier in classifiers_list:
        val += "Classifier:  " + classifier + '\n'

    val += "Requires-Python: " + requires_pyhon + '\n'
    val += "Description-Content-Type: " + description_content_type + '\n'
    val += "Provides-Extra: " + provides_extra + '\n'

    val += '\n' + long_description + '\n'

    return val


def check_ext(filename, ext_filter) -> bool:
    """
    Check of the file complies with the list of extensions
    :param filename: filename
    :param ext_filter: list of extnsions
    :return: true/false
    """
    for ext in ext_filter:
        if filename.endswith(ext):
            return True
    return False


def find_pkg_files(path: str, ext_filter=['.py']) -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
    """
    Get list
    :param path: path to traverse
    :param ext_filter: extensions of files to include
    :return: list of [filename, complete path
    """
    files_list = list()
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        for fname in filenames:
            if check_ext(filename=fname, ext_filter=ext_filter):
                pth = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
                files_list.append((fname, pth))

    return files_list


def build_tar_gz_pkg(pkg_name: str,
                     setup_path: str,
                     version: str,
                     summary: str,
                     home_page: str,
                     author: str,
                     email: str,
                     license_: str,
                     keywords: str,
                     classifiers_list: List[str],
                     requires_pyhon: str,
                     description_content_type: str,
                     provides_extra: str,
                     long_description: str,
                     folder_to_save='dist',
                     ext_filter=['py']):
    """

    :param pkg_name:
    :param setup_path:
    :param version:
    :param summary:
    :param home_page:
    :param author:
    :param email:
    :param license_:
    :param keywords:
    :param classifiers_list:
    :param requires_pyhon:
    :param description_content_type:
    :param provides_extra:
    :param long_description:
    :param folder_to_save:
    :param ext_filter:
    :return:
    """
    pkg_name2 = pkg_name + '-' + version
    filename = pkg_name2 + '.tar.gz'
    output_filename = os.path.join(folder_to_save, filename)

    files = find_pkg_files(path=pkg_name,
                           ext_filter=ext_filter)

    pkg_info = build_pkg_info(name=pkg_name,
                              version=version,
                              summary=summary,
                              home_page=home_page,
                              author=author,
                              email=email,
                              license_=license_,
                              keywords=keywords,
                              classifiers_list=classifiers_list,
                              requires_pyhon=requires_pyhon,
                              description_content_type=description_content_type,
                              provides_extra=provides_extra,
                              long_description=long_description)
    pkg_info_path = 'pkg_info' + pkg_name
    with open(pkg_info_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pkg_info)

    setup_cfg = build_setup_cfg()
    setup_cfg_path = 'setup_cfg' + pkg_name
    with open(setup_cfg_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(setup_cfg)

    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        for name, file_path in files:
            if not name.endswith('setup.py'):
                tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, file_path))

        # add the setup where it belongs
        tar.add(setup_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'setup.py'))

        # add
        tar.add(pkg_info_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'PKG-INFO'))
        tar.add(setup_cfg_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'setup.cfg'))

    os.remove(pkg_info_path)
    os.remove(setup_cfg_path)

    return output_filename


def build_wheel(pkg_name: str,
                setup_path: str,
                version: str,
                summary: str,
                home_page: str,
                author: str,
                email: str,
                license_: str,
                keywords: str,
                classifiers_list: List[str],
                requires_pyhon: str,
                description_content_type: str,
                provides_extra: str,
                long_description: str,
                folder_to_save='dist',
                ext_filter=['py']):
    """

    :param pkg_name:
    :param setup_path:
    :param version:
    :param summary:
    :param home_page:
    :param author:
    :param email:
    :param license_:
    :param keywords:
    :param classifiers_list:
    :param requires_pyhon:
    :param description_content_type:
    :param provides_extra:
    :param long_description:
    :param folder_to_save:
    :param ext_filter:
    :return:
    """

    pkg_name2 = pkg_name + '-' + version
    filename = pkg_name2 + '.whl'
    output_filename = os.path.join(folder_to_save, filename)

    files = find_pkg_files(path=pkg_name,
                           ext_filter=ext_filter)

    pkg_info = build_pkg_info(name=pkg_name,
                              version=version,
                              summary=summary,
                              home_page=home_page,
                              author=author,
                              email=email,
                              license_=license_,
                              keywords=keywords,
                              classifiers_list=classifiers_list,
                              requires_pyhon=requires_pyhon,
                              description_content_type=description_content_type,
                              provides_extra=provides_extra,
                              long_description=long_description)
    pkg_info_path = 'pkg_info' + pkg_name
    with open(pkg_info_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pkg_info)

    setup_cfg = build_setup_cfg()
    setup_cfg_path = 'setup_cfg' + pkg_name
    with open(setup_cfg_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(setup_cfg)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_filename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)as tar:
        for name, file_path in files:
            if not name.endswith('setup.py'):
                tar.write(file_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, file_path))

        # add the setup where it belongs
        tar.write(setup_path, arcname=os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'setup.py'))

        # add
        tar.writestr(os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'PKG-INFO'), data=pkg_info)
        tar.writestr(os.path.join(pkg_name2, 'setup.cfg'), data=setup_cfg_path)

    os.remove(pkg_info_path)
    os.remove(setup_cfg_path)

    return output_filename


def read_pypirc() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """
    Read the pypirc file located in home
    :return: user, password
    """
    home = Path.home()
    path = os.path.join(home, 'pypirc')

    with open(path) as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

    user = ''
    pwd = ''
    for line in lines:
        if '=' in line:
            key, val = line.split('=')

            if key.strip() == 'username':
                user = val.strip()
            elif key.strip() == 'password':
                pwd = val.strip()

    return user, pwd


def publish(pkg_name: str,
            setup_path: str,
            version: str,
            summary: str,
            home_page: str,
            author: str,
            email: str,
            license_: str,
            keywords: str,
            classifiers_list: List[str],
            requires_pyhon: str,
            description_content_type: str,
            provides_extra: str,
            long_description: str):
    """
    Publish package to Pypi using twine
    :param pkg_name: name of the package (i.e GridCal)
    :param setup_path: path to the package setup.py (i.e. GridCal/setup.py)
    :param version: verison of the package (i.e. 5.1.0)
    :param summary:
    :param home_page:
    :param author:
    :param email:
    :param license_:
    :param keywords:
    :param classifiers_list:
    :param requires_pyhon:
    :param description_content_type:
    :param provides_extra:
    :param long_description:
    """

    # build the tar.gz file
    fpath = build_tar_gz_pkg(pkg_name=pkg_name,
                             setup_path=setup_path,
                             version=version,
                             summary=summary,
                             home_page=home_page,
                             author=author,
                             email=email,
                             license_=license_,
                             keywords=keywords,
                             classifiers_list=classifiers_list,
                             requires_pyhon=requires_pyhon,
                             description_content_type=description_content_type,
                             provides_extra=provides_extra,
                             long_description=long_description,
                             folder_to_save='dist',
                             ext_filter=['.py', '.csv', '.txt'])

    # check the tar.gz file
    call([sys.executable, '-m', 'twine', 'check', fpath])

    user, pwd = read_pypirc()

    # upload the tar.gz file
    call([sys.executable, '-m', 'twine', 'upload',
          '--repository', 'pypi',
          '--username', user,
          '--password', pwd,
          fpath])
```

This allows me to have the structure exactu how I want it and stil produce pip-correct packages.

```
repository_folder
|
|_ src
    |_ GridCal
    |     |_ GUI
    |     |_ __init__.py
    |     |_ setup.py 
    |
    |_ GridCalEngine
    |     |_ Core
    |     |_ IO
    |     |_ Simulations
    |     |_ __init__.py
    |     |_ setup.py 
    |
    |_ upload_to_pypi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot move `setup.py` outside the package move the package
inside a subdirectory. This is the recommended structure with flat
layout:

```
repository_folder
|
|_ GridCal
|  |_ GridCal
|  |  |     |_ GUI
|  |  |     |_ __init__.py
|  |_ setup.py 
|
|_ GridCalEngine
|  |_ GridCalEngine
|  |  |     |_ Core
|  |  |     |_ IO
|  |  |     |_ Simulations
|  |  |     |_ __init__.py
|  |_ setup.py 
|
|_ upload_to_pypi.py
```

or src-layout:

```
repository_folder
|
|_ GridCal
|  _ src
|  |_ GridCal
|  |     |_ GUI
|  |     |_ __init__.py
|  |_ setup.py 
|
|_ GridCalEngine
|  _ src
|  |  |_ GridCalEngine
|  |     |_ Core
|  |     |_ IO
|  |     |_ Simulations
|  |     |_ __init__.py
|  |_ setup.py 
|
|_ upload_to_pypi.py
```

Comment: wouldn't that modify the access paths to `from GridCal.src.GUI import ...`?

Comment: if you think you know the answer it would be good to know about it.

Comment: i think the solution is invalid because it heavily modifies the import paths. Instean of having `from GridCal import Gui`, I'd have to use `from GridCal.src import Gui` which I won't do. Unless this is not the case and things work out in a way I don't know about. Also in your solutions the setup are still inside the package, so the problem is the same but with an extra folder (src)

Comment: `setup.py`s are not inside packages, because `src`s are not parts of the packages. Imports are not modified because `src`s are not parts of the packages hence are not parts of import. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12997198/7976758

Comment: Well, just moved things to `/src` and as expected everything breaks: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GridCal.__version__'` now it should be `GridCal.src.__version__`

Comment: Also, the docs say: `The src layout requires installation of the project to be able to run its code, and the flat layout does not.`this is exactly what I want to avoid. I need the engine to be debuggable along with the rest.

Comment: Yep, you're righ. My bad, I'm very sorry. I lost intermidiate subdirectories. I redrew the answer with flat and src layouts.

Comment: I ended up writing my own packaging code...see below